# How can I stop Doxygen from generating a Packages index for a C# project?

Tags: c#, html, doxygen, chm

I'm using Doxygen for the first time with a C# project. In the .chm output (compiled html), it shows a "Packages" hierarchy corresponding to the C# namespaces. I'd like to hide the section entirely, but if that's not possible, then at least it should call it namespaces instead of packages.

I'm using  type C# markup, not the proprietary Doxygen format.

I'm guessing that "Packages" is for java apps, not C#.

In the .chm index, I see three highest-level nodes on the tree: A project overview subtree, a Packages subtree, and a Classes subtree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Doxywizard, there is a radio button in Wizard => Mode called *Optimize for Java or C#* output. DON'T CHOOSE IT. Choose *Optimize for C++ output* instead. Must be a bug in Doxygen or something.

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered.

Comment: Do you know what exact option in the Doxyfile was causing the "Packages" hierarchy to be generated?